# .Net Core 6 Static Property for library version

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware, .net-6.0

Requirement - Need to add version information to all api responses. .Net 6 / WebApi / C#

Possible Solution - Added a custom middleware to add version information to all api responses. In this middleware, I am using reflection to get assembly version, and adding it to header.

Query - I do not want to continually use reflection for all api responses. If I can just get the information once, and then re-use it for all responses, that would save me a lot of reflection operations. Below is my middleware code,

```
public class CustomHeaderMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CustomHeaderMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Version", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString());
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

But where I am stuck is, how to do so effectively?
Add a static class somewhere, and then use it? Like we do with extensions.
Is there a possible way to do this in program.cs?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Add the version as a static field in `CustomHeaderMiddleware`?

Comment: Version would only normally update on new release.  Why not just store it in your configuration file or use the AssemblyInfo file.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping it simple, add a [Lazy<>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=net-6.0) static field to your middleware, and access it from your middleware.

Something like

```cs
public class CustomHeaderMiddleware
{
    private static Lazy<string> _version = new Lazy<string>(GetVersion);

    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CustomHeaderMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Version", _version.Value);
        await _next(context);
    }

    private static string GetVersion() => 
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
}
```

Because it's [lazy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/lazy-initialization), the value will only be calculated once, on first access to the middleware. This guarantees the reflection cost is only paid once. The `GetVersion()` local function itself must be static.

You could move the `GetVersion()` code to `program.cs`, call it during startup, and instead set a static `Version` property on the middleware, but that has the drawback of violating encapsulation, and having two places to go for maintenance.

Comment: I would argue that even Lazy is not needed, just static field should be fine.

Comment: I went ahead with this response (including lazy). This works for me ! marked as answer and useful too.

Comment: @GuruStron you may be right. I wasn't sure in what assembly the middleware was coded and had doubts about `GetExecutingAssembly`. Maybe I was thinking it was `GetEntryAssembly()` or something...

Comment: @Anshul you might try GuruStron's suggestion. It does simplify it even more.